# Разделение предложения на слова

Tags: c++

Клиент посылает серверу char строку вида "Слово1 Слово2". Посылает это всё одной переменной
Нужно сделать так что бы Слово1 занеслось в одну переменную, а Слово2 во вторую переменную. Так сказать сделать так что бы Слово1 до пробела копировалось в одну переменную и Слово2 после пробела в другую. Опыты с strtok и strstr не помогли.

Как примерно должна выглядеть реализация?

Comment: Берете в руки отладчик и разбираетесь со строковыми функциями. И да, посылаются байты...

Comment: @OverLoader А какая проблема возникла с strtok?

Comment: Если максимальный размер слов известен, то IMHO самый простой способ -- `sscanf()` (см. man sscanf) (пуристы скажут, что это Си, а не С++, но компилятору это до лампочки).

Comment: На всякий случай, вдруг где-то еще пригодиться, вот пара удобных функций [strtos.c](http://pastebin.com/6XBP0KZH) и [str_locword.c](http://pastebin.com/vFQNMV3Y) для вытаскивания слов из сишных строк.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string data = "word1 word2";
  std::istringstream is(data);
  std::string word1, word2;
  is >> word1 >> word2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то тоже была такая задача, сделал такой алгоритм (довольно универсальный)

Сами напишете функцию `IsCurrentSymbolIsSeparator(wchar_t symbol)`, которая возвращает, является ли поданный ей символ разделителем (так сами можете определить, чем могут слова в принципе разделяться.

```
size_t length = wcslen(input);

bool isPreviousCharWasSeparator = true;
int wordNumber = 0;
int wordStart = -1;

for (size_t i = 0; i <= length; ++i)
{
    bool isCurrentCharSeparator = IsCurrentSymbolIsSeparator(input[i]);
    bool isNewWordStart = isPreviousCharWasSeparator && !isCurrentCharSeparator;

    if (isNewWordStart)
    {
        ++wordNumber;
        wordStart = i;
    }

    bool isWordEnd = !isPreviousCharWasSeparator && isCurrentCharSeparator;

    if (isWordEnd)
    {
        wcsncat(result, input + wordStart, i - wordStart);
        wcscat(result, L" ");
        //итого в result будет очередное слово.
    }

    isPreviousCharWasSeparator = isCurrentCharSeparator;
}
```

P.S. Сделано для wchar_t, но разницы никакой

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, вы имеете дело с символьными массивами.

Попробуйте следующий подход

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "   Word1 Word2";
    char s1[6], s2[6];

    std::istringstream is( s );

    is >> std::ws;

    is.getline( s1, sizeof( s1 ), ' ' );

    is >> std::ws;

    is.getline( s2, sizeof( s2 ), ' ' );

    std::cout << "s1 = \"" << s1 << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "s2 = \"" << s2 << "\"\n";
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
s1 = "Word1"
s2 = "Word2"
```

Если вместо символьных массивов использовать класс `std::string`, то вместо функции `getline` можно было бы просто использовать `operator >>`